# Parameters of Reasoning - auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice

In einem englischsprachigen philosophischen Artikel von Iris Marion Young, über den ich in einem Seminar sprechen werde, heißt ein Abschnitt "Parameters of Reasoning". Wie würde das ins Deutsche übersetzt? Alle Möglichkeiten scheinen mir zu mathematisch zu sein.

In dem Text ("Responsibility and Global Justice") schlägt Young ein neues Model für persönliche und institutionelle Verantwortung vor. "Parameters of Reasoning" ist in Bezug auf dieses Model, das Young *social connection model* nennt - also nicht über *reasoning* selbst (keines logisch-theoretisches Thema). Es geht (nachdem das Model vorgeschlagen worden ist) darum, wie der *agent* (privat oder institutionell) seine Verantwortung betrachten sollte.

Comment: *Einflüsse auf*...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der Text ist [hier](https://books.google.de/books?id=aaNgZrMdx-UC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=%22parameters%20of%20reasoning%22&source=bl&ots=JXHyfZL_dh&sig=beDdi6Gdmiy5U1awWf-sbba3QsI&hl=de&sa=X&ei=Z-KrVLHPEYbkUuiZgPAO&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22parameters%20of%20reasoning%22&f=false) und die vier Parameter sind: power, privilege, interest and collective ability. 
Diese vier Gesichtspunkte sollen zur Entscheidungsfindung beitragen.
Vor diesem Hintergrund denke ich die beste Übersetzung für "parameter" ist:

> Kriterien

Das Wort "reasoning" ist ein bisschen ein Problem, da es sich schlecht treffend in einem Wort übersetzen lässt. Man könnte das Ganze

> Evaluationskriterien

nennen, aber das ist erstens klobig und zweitens zu sehr auf das "danach" fokussiert. 
Ich denke, es wäre am besten, eine Phrase mit einem der folgenden Wörter zu finden

> Fragestellungen, Anhaltspunkte, Fragen oder Aspekte

und das "reasoning" ganz raus zu lassen.

Comment: *Gesichtspunkte* passt vielleicht auch. Ist in gewisser Weise Teil deiner Antwort, aber nicht wirklich herausgestellt.

Comment: @Timbo... ja, ich hatte aus irgendeinem Grund das Gefühl es ist nicht überschriftentauglich. Daher hab' ich es nicht extra erwähnt.

Answer (score 0):

> Die Grenzen der Vernunft

is my suggestion.